# Another user’s hat popping up in top-left corner

Tags: bug, winter-bash

I just visited [the Convention badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention) and noticed the top-left corner has something popping up:

[image: something weird popping up]

I clicked it and ended up on [Spencer Wieczorek’s profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3149020/spencer-wieczorek). I have no idea who that is.

It’s also sensible to mouse hover:

[image: it mouseovers!]

I don’t know if this is a bug, a feature, or [jazz](https://twitter.com/kytrinyx/status/663428184411537408), but I thought to report it just in case.

Some more information:

- Spencer does show up about halfway through the page; his avatar is empty white
- Hovering on Spencer’s white avatar has the same pop-up in the upper left corner
- Hovering on someone else’s (e.g. Barmar, line above Spencer) avatar has their pop-up right on that spot
- The same also happened on a question/answers page, with a different user (sorry, forgot to save the link), so it’s not specific to one kind of page on the site, and it affects hats of at least two users

Comment: Dirty browser cache probably, press Ctrl+F5.  If that works then you surely want to post to superuser.com next.

Comment: @HansPassant nope, not a cache issue (tried Ctrl-F5 even).

Comment: Do you use an exotic OS or browser?

Comment: @CodeCaster Firefox 38.3.0 ESR, official Mozilla binaries for i386, on Debian sid/x32 (exotic, but as it’s an i386 binary it only gets Debian sid/i386 libraries), under IceWM as window manager. Shouldn’t be a cause, methinks. But, interestingly enough, I cannot reproduce this with Iceweasel 38.5.0esr-1 (sid/amd64, same machine, Multi-Arch)…

Comment: *"I have no idea who that is"*, yeah me neither. Although more than likely that user happen to be the newest users that got awarded that badge at the time.